# The meaning of "by that cork yonder"

Tags: meaning

The following is from ["The Manner of Men"](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/limits/chapter19.html) by Kipling (emphasis mine):

> ‘Just darning the water again, as we had done from Myra to Cnidus,’ said Quabil ruefully. ‘I daren’t stand out. There was the bone-yard of all the Gulf of Africa under my lee. But at last we worked into Fairhaven — **by that cork yonder**. Late as it was, I should have taken her on, but I had to call a ship-council as to lying up for the winter. That Rhodian law may have suited open boats and cock-crow coasters,1 but it’s childish for ocean-traffic.’

I do not understand the meaning of *by that cork yonder*.

I am glad if some one would kindly teach me.

Comment: I edited your question to fix the URL and provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence makes sense only in the context of the story. The sailors are describing a voyage while drinking together. The one telling the tale is using odds and ends, like dates and corks, to construct a crude map on a tabletop. So the harbor that he is talking would be on the map close to the point indicated by the cork.